How to list all file in a path with absolute path and spaces in a script
I'm writing a script that accept a path as a parameter and process all the .mkv file in the path. The path could be an absolute path, a relative path, or even a single file. However, I still need the absolute path of the files I'm iterating.
This is what I've done so far:
#!/bin/bash

path=$1
if ! [ -e "$path" ]; then
  path=$(pwd)
fi

find "$path" -type f -name '*.mkv' | sort | xargs realpath | while read file; do
  echo "Processing $file"
done

This works when there is no spaces in path and/or file, but fail with spaces.
What is the right way to do it?

You can preprocess the path itself rather than all the files:
find "$(realpath -- "$path")" -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec printf 'Processing %s\n' {} +

Replace printf by whatever it is you actually want to do with the files. + indicates that several files can be processed in each invocation; if that’s not the case, use \; instead.

With zsh:
#! /bin/zsh -
for file (${${1-.}:P}/**/*.mkv(ND.))
  print -r processing $file


${1-.} like in the Bourne shell expands to . if $1 is not set (if $# == 0; if would be a poor interface to do it rather when $1 is a non-existing file as that would be quite surprising to the user)
${param:P} expands to the realpath() of that expansion. No need to do the same for each file as **/ doesn't follow symlinks and the . qualifier selects only regular files, so not symlinks.
**/ matches any level of subdirectories
Glob qualifiers N for nullglob, D for dotglob, . for regular only.


Hm, what about this one-liner: printf 'Processing %s…\n' ${${1-.}:P}/**/*.mkv(ND.) ?

@MarcusMüller, that would not give the correct output when there's no match, but I think the printing is just a placeholder for whatever the OP really wants to do with those files.

Agreeing with Stephen here, always prefer -exec to trying to post-process find's output. If you really need to, always use -print0 to allow for unambiguous delimiting of file names; most tools that consume file names from their input support some sort of --null, --zero/-z or -0 flag to make them interpret input as separated with 0 bytes.
In your case, I'd probably prefer zsh, but assuming you want to stick with bash, you can do the same without any of your problems. You can omit the sort, because globbing happens alphabetically ordered, anyways. You can omit find, because bash can do recursive globbing just as well (zsh could also constrain the file type while globbing, in bash we actually need to test with -f for file-ness), and you can omit xargs because you're handling one file at a time, anyways:
#!/bin/bash
# Fail when something goes wrong!
set -e
# enable recursive globs, and don't fail when there's nothing there
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob
shopt -s nullglob

inpath="$1"
if ! [ -e "${inpath}" ]; then
  inpath="$(pwd)"
fi

for file in "${inpath}/**/*.mkv"; do
  # check whether regular file, skip if not
  [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
  fullpath="$(realpath -- "${file}")"
  echo  "Processing ${fullpath}" # Could / might prefer to use printf here instead
done

You can sort things differently, in case the default sorting really isn't what you need. You would need to replace
for file in "${inpath}/**/*.mkv"; do

with something along the lines of
unsorted=( ${inpath}/**/*.mkv )
readarray -d '' -t sorted_files < \
    <(printf '%s\0' "${unsorted[@]}" \
        | sort -z --whateveroptions \
     )
for file in "${sorted_files[@]}" ; do

readarray has the -d option which sets the delimiter to the string passed; passing the empty string makes it use zero bytes as delimiters. readarray's -t trims (we shouldn't need that here, but I found it a safe default), sort -z uses the zero byte as delimiter. "${arrayname[@]}" expands to an iterable list of elements from that array, but all safe for usage even with spaces and newlines in the elements.
In zsh, you can also sort files found via globbing. Use zsh, when you can.
